# Typescript compiler outputs strange symbol for £ sign

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

The TypeScript:

```
var options = <Options>{
    currencySymbol: "£"
};
```

Is output as this in JavaScript

```
var options = {
    currencySymbol: "�"
};
```

Using TypeScriptToolsVersion 2.3.2 in the .proj file, and Version 2.3.2 is installed via NPM.

Note that this output only occurs through the Visual Studio build process, and not via compile on save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change encoding of file but this option is in Visual Studio 2017 little bit complicated. First you need too add this function to GUI.

In **Standard Toolbar options** button press **Add or Remove Buttons** and **Customize** (if you are lost, see screenshot)

[image: Customizing standard panel]

In opened dialog press **Add Command...** in Categories select **File** and choose **Advanced Save Options...**

[image: Adding command to standard panel]

Then comfirm **OK** next **Close**. In standard panel appear new button Advanced Save Options. Just click it

[image: New Advanced Save Options button]

choose **Unicode (UTF-8 with signature)** and confirm **OK**. File get changed. Save it. Rebuild solution to get file transpiled.

[image: changing file encoding in Visual Studio]